# Insert DIV container below 1st search result

Tags: search

How can I insert a DIV just below the first search result (between result #1 and #2)?

Comment: Show us the search.php code and what do you want to include exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do that with:

```
/**
 * Setup a custom hook before the second post on the search page
 */
add_action( 'the_post', function( $post, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( $q->is_search() && $q->is_main_query() && 2 === $q->current_post )
    {
        do_action( 'wpse_before_second_post_in_search' );
    }
}, 10, 2 ); 

/**
 * Inject a Div after the first post on the search page
 */
add_action( 'wpse_before_second_post_in_search', function()
{
    echo '<div>My Injected Div</div>';
} );
```

where we've introduced the custom `wpse_before_second_post_in_search` hook, that you can now play with as you need.

Comment: Interesting approach ;-). Just one note, shouldn't you use `the_posts` filter instead of `the_post`, or am I missing something obvious here

Comment: thanks, I'm always doing some typos ;-) here I actually I wanted to target `the_post` action, hehe I'm somewhat still sleeping .. @PieterGoosen

Comment: I was actually sleeping :-), slipped away for an hour to take a power nap. Have the flu and the medicine caught up with me, hahahaha

Comment: Hope you get well soon, you could try the undocumented `wp_delete_flu()` ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: Hahahaha, excellent solution, `if ( have_flu() ) { while ( have_flu() ) { the_flu(); /* Insert bugs and virusses here to be trashed */ } wp_delete_flu(); }`. Enjoy

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you @kat

Comment: Awesome solution.  I have two questions: Do you think an anonymous function is the cleanest / most readable way to do this? For example, why not just `add_action('the_post', 'my_custom_search_function', 10, 2)` and break the function out explicitly?  And while I understand the type hinting with the WP_Query in the function arguments, is it really necessary in this case?  Thanks for the feedback - I just like to understand so I can learn!

Comment: Glad you found it somewhat useful. I always struggle to find good function names, so I usually prefer *anonymous* functions, when posting short snippets here on [wordpress.se] ;-) Both are valid, so just choose what suits you best. Though it might be better to use regular function callbacks, if you need to remove them later.  In these short snippets I also prefer the `$q` variable name, for the `WP_Query` instance (looks cleaner than `$query` and I don't want to use the global `$wp_query`  name ) so I use the type hinting to show what it is. But you can skip that too if you want. @cale_b