# How to hook into search results template or query?

Tags: plugins, search, content

I am looking for a way to hook into the search results from a regular WordPress site search and make changes either to the display of the results themselves (by hooking into `search.php` somehow - not possible, I don't think), or failing that to hook into the results of the query AFTER the query is executed but before `search.php` gets hold of the query, so I can insert an extra "result" of my own or modify a result.

I know about `pre_get_posts()`, but I don't think altering the actual query is going to help me.

To simplify the question - I want to add content to search results pages. Think, adding a banner before or after the search results, or even within the content of one of the results.

Altering `search.php` or adding any theme files is out of the question, I need to do this from within a WP plugin and have it work on any WP site.

I am kind of stumped...

Comment: This [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188861/insert-div-container-below-1st-search-result) is related.

Comment: Ahh, well-found, I had failed to turn up that post for all my searching. That solution would be workable, I think. Thanks.